# csp uploading file from desktop to var folder

Tags: ssh, centos, scp

I am trying to send an sql dump file from my desktop to my vps.

I tried this command exactly.

```
scp C:/users/ioi/desktop/localhost.sql root@327.25.10.15:var/www/public
```

It is giving me an error that says

```
 Name or service not known
[root@vps-7174-4454 public]# scp C:/users/ioi/desktop/localhost.sql root@327.25.10.15:var/www/public/
ssh: Could not resolve hostname C: Name or service not known
```

I don't understand why it won't recognize the C: part. Anyone has any idea?

Comment: why does the file path contain c:/  ?  This is a strange name for a unix file system.  try putting single or double quotes around the filename

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't recognise the C: part is that scp uses a colon to separate the hostname from the filename. So scp thinks C is the hostname and it fails to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are on correct machine/terminal. On windows scp `C:/Users/...` works, but I was executing it on remote linux instead of local command line.